# doWork is not being called of WorkoutManager

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am trying to migrate gcmnetworkmanager to workmanager. This is the code I have used :
This code is called in the mainActivity

```
WorkRequest uploadWorkRequest =
              new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncServiceV2.class)
                    .build();

        WorkManager
              .getInstance(context)
              .enqueue(uploadWorkRequest);
```

This is the worker class :

```
class SyncServiceV2 extends Worker {
    public SyncServiceV2(@NonNull @NotNull Context context,
                         @NonNull @NotNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);

    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        return syncBadgeData();
    }
```

But the doWork is not being called. What is wrong in my code. Why is the code not being called?

Comment: did u put some log and check , or try the debugger

Comment: Yes, there is no log also. which is why I am confused as of what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

Use: **adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler**

Then you can check what is the state of your work. There might be some constraints still not satisfied.

```
Required constraints: TIMING_DELAY CONNECTIVITY [0x90000000] 
Satisfied constraints: DEVICE_NOT_DOZING BACKGROUND_NOT_RESTRICTED WITHIN_QUOTA [0x3400000]  
Unsatisfied constraints: TIMING_DELAY CONNECTIVITY [0x90000000]
```

Check: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging